# Homework Help regarding python

Tags: python-3.x

How do I do this in python?

The first function you will write should be called ‘wordSalad’. Your function should take four (4)
arguments, all strings. The function should return one (1) string formatted as follows: ‘I love
 and  with  and .’

Example Test Case:
wordSalad(‘Bob’, ‘Joe’, ‘lemonade’, ‘pizza’)

returns
I love Bob and Joe with lemonade and pizza.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need help? Have you tried to ask your instructor? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 2):

```
def wordSalad(a,b,c,d):
    return "I love "+a+" and "+b+" with "+c+" and "+d+'.'
```

Try this. You just need to concatenate the strings. You could also use string formatting.

```
def wordSalad(a,b,c,d):
    return 'I love {} and {} with {} and {}.'.format(a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @WHACKAMADOODLE3000 s answer, you could also use %s. (A little less typing)

```
def wordSalad(a, b, c, d):
    return 'I love %s and %s with %s and %s.' % (a, b, c, d)
```